# Why am I getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException?

Tags: java

I am not sure why when I run it, it manages to get past the first part but once it runs through the number and prints them all out. But once that is done it shows `java.lang.ArrayindexOutOfBoundsException`.

```
package database;
import java.util.Scanner;    
public class Run {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int counting =0;
        int count =  0;
        int totalAddUp =0;
        int finalNumber = 0;
        int searchingPlus = 0;
        int caseSwitching = 0;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int userLength = 1000000000;

        System.out.println("Please enter the number you wish to find exponentially: ");
        int userInput = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Please enter the length in which you wish to find: ");
        counting = scan.nextInt();

        int[] array = new int[counting];

        for(int i = 0; i < array.length + 1; i++) {

            finalNumber = userInput + finalNumber;
            array[totalAddUp] = finalNumber;
            System.out.println(array[totalAddUp]);
            totalAddUp++;
        }

        System.out.println("Press 1 to search for a certain number or press 2 to end the program");

        switch(caseSwitching) {

        case 1:
            System.out.println("Please enter a number in which you would like to search");
            int searching = scan.nextInt();
            while(searchingPlus > userInput) {
                if(userInput == array[searchingPlus]) {
                    System.out.println(array[searchingPlus]);
                }
                searchingPlus++;
            }

            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("Thanks have a great day");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what your `case 1:` is trying to do ?

Comment: Try with i<array.length

Comment: >      for(int i = 0; i < array.length + 1; i++)  this is wrong

Answer (score 4):

You got `java.lang.ArrayindexOutOfBoundsException` because in your `for` loop you are going to `array.lenth + 1`.

Try this:

```
 for(int i = 0; i < array.length ; i++) {

        finalNumber = userInput + finalNumber;
        array[totalAddUp] = finalNumber;
        System.out.println(array[totalAddUp]);
        totalAddUp++;
    }
```

And also another problem to your code is when you output

```
        System.out.println("Press 1 to search for a certain number or press 2 to end the program");
```

and you don't have any input to get.

Answer (score 0):

Please note the following loop:

```
 for(int i = 0; i < array.length + 1; i++) {

        finalNumber = userInput + finalNumber;
        array[totalAddUp] = finalNumber;
        System.out.println(array[totalAddUp]);
        totalAddUp++;
    }
```

Array are indexed starting from `0` till their respective `length`. So, you are trying to manipulate the array items at index in range `[0,1,...,length,length+1]` which raises the `ArrayindexOutOfBoundsException` exception.

So you can use:

```
     for(int i = 0; i < array.length ; i++) {

        finalNumber = userInput + finalNumber;
        array[totalAddUp] = finalNumber;
        System.out.println(array[totalAddUp]);
        totalAddUp++;
    }
```

Also, please note to add the following line to read a value into `caseSwitching`:

caseSwitching = scan.nextInt();

Answer (score 0):

for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

```
        finalNumber = userInput + finalNumber;
        array[totalAddUp] = finalNumber;
        System.out.println(array[totalAddUp]);
        totalAddUp++;
    }
```

in here this should work because of "array.length+1" increase array limit